# receive unicast and multicast data using a single socket

Tags: c, sockets

I am developing a network based application wherein I want to receive both unicast and multicast data. So I want to know whether it is possible to receive both unicast data and multicast data using a single socket. This is my code, as of now I am only able to receive unicast data but not multicast data.

```
void* rec(void* t)
{
    printf("Rec Thread created\n");
    char buf[200];
    struct sockaddr_in soc;
    soc.sin_family=AF_INET;
    soc.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("123.1.2.3");
    soc.sin_port=htons(1234);

    long sock_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);

    bind(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&soc,sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    memset(&mreq,0,sizeof(struct ip_mreq));
    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr=inet_addr("235.5.5.5");
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr=inet_addr("123.1.2.3");

    setsockopt(sock_fd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,&mreq,sizeof(mreq)) 

    while(true)
    {
        memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
        long size=recvfrom(sock_fd,buf,200,0,NULL,NULL);
        if(size>0)
        {
            printf("recvd %s\n",buf);
        }
        else
        {
            perror("Error receving data");
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    pthread_create(&pt,NULL,rec,NULL);
    sleep(2);
    char buf[]="Hello World!;
    struct sockaddr_in soc;
    soc.sin_family=AF_INET;
    soc.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("123.1.2.3");
    soc.sin_port=htons(1234);

    long sock_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);

    sendto(sock_fd,buf,sizeof(buf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&soc,sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    struct sockaddr_in msoc;
    msoc.sin_family=AF_INET;
    msoc.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("235.5.5.5");
    msoc.sin_port=htons(1234);

    char mbuf[]="Hi All!";
    sendto(sock_fd,mbuf,sizeof(mbuf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&msoc,sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Multicast data is UDP. So what do you mean by "both UDP and multicast data"?

Comment: @Barmar I mean both point-to-point and multicast data

Comment: I don't think you can do it. In order to receive multicast data you have to join the multicast group, which is like binding to a specific local address. Then it won't receive packets sent to any other address, including the machine's real IP.

Comment: Do you really need to use the same socket for both? Why not use two sockets, and use `select()` to wait for a packet on either of them?

Comment: @Barmar I can use another socket, but want to know if it is possible using a single socket

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Or at least 'kind-of' possible.

Consider following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(void) {
    struct sockaddr_in vSSocket;
    vSSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
    vSSocket.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    vSSocket.sin_port = htons(1234);

    int vSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (vSocket < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    struct ip_mreq vReq;
    vReq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("235.5.5.5");
    vReq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("123.1.2.3");
    if (setsockopt(vSocket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &vReq, sizeof(vReq)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt 2");
        return 1;
    }
    if (bind(vSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&vSSocket, sizeof(vSSocket)) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        return 1;
    }
    ssize_t r;
    char vBuf[256];
    while (1) {
        r = recv(vSocket, vBuf, sizeof(vBuf), 0);
        if (r < 0) {
            perror("recv");
            break;
        }
        if (memcmp(vBuf, "quit", 4) == 0) {
            printf("quit\n");
            break;
        }
        write(1, vBuf, r);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The trick is: you bind your socket to `INADDR_ANY` address. So it will listen on **every** interface your machine has. Additionally, interface that has address 123.1.2.3 joins multicast group 235.5.5.5, so it will receive any packet for that address.

You can test this solution using superb `socat` tool.
To send to multicast address:

```
socat STDIO UDP4-DATAGRAM:235.5.5.5:1234
```

To send to unicast address:

```
socat STDIO UDP4-DATAGRAM:123.1.2.3:1234
```

The program should output anything you send to it and quit upon reception of a packet beginning with 'quit'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. nsilent22 has the first 90%.

- Bind the socket to `INADDR_ANY`
- Set `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` (ipv6: `IPV6_JOIN_GROUP`)
- If sending is required, set `IP_MULTICAST_IF` (ipv6: `IPV6_MULTICAST_IF`) to set the output interface of multicast packets.

This gets you a socket that listens on a multicast group, but also receives all unicast traffic to the machine. To limit it to a single interface, you have two options:

- Set `IP_PKTINFO` (ipv6: `IPV6_RECVPKTINFO`), receive data using recvmsg, and filter received data based on the `ipi_ifindex` member of the `in_pktinfo` structure (ipv6: `ipi6_ifindex` member of `struct in6_pktinfo`).
- Set the (linux specific) socket option `SO_BINDTODEVICE` (root privileges required)

This way you get a socket that receives multicast traffic from select multicast groups, as well as all unicast traffic, but limited to a single interface.

Sources: manpages for ip,ipv6 and socket.